# How can I determine how many $B$-smooth numbers are below a given number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algorithms

Suppose I have a factor Basis with primes $F =\{2, 3, \dots, B \}$ and I want to know how many numbers exist in the range

$1 \leq 2^{a_2}3^{a_3} \dots B^{a_{B}} \leq N$ for a natural number $N$ with exponents $a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{B}$. Such numbers are called $B$-smooth numbers. In the Special case where $B=5$ we have all Hamming numbers below $N$. I tried to use recursion which worked, but at extremely high numbers and especially if we have a very large factor Basis (means more numbers are possible), the recursion method that counts the number of $B$-smooth numbers would be extremely slow. Details to my method that works, but will be slow when $B$ is a large prime:

$n_{N,B} = \sum_{i=1}^{log_BN}n_{N/i,B'}$

Here, $n_{N,B}$ is the number of $B$-smooth numbers below $N$ and $B'$ is the prime that is exactly previous to $B$ (in other words: $B>B'$ where $B$ is the prime coming exactly after $B'$). I divide the number $N$ (Floor division) by the largest prime factor until it is Zero and obtain a sequence of numbers for each I repeat the procedure with lower prime factors. The recursion will return $n_{N,1}=1$ if $N$ nonzero at the end (I define 1 as the (trivial prime) number that denotes that the recursion stops there).

Besides this I have read about approximate functions that count the number of $B$-smooth numbers (Look for "Brujin function" when interested). But how I can determine the number of $B$-smooth numbers more efficiently without sacrificing accuracy? Somebody has some hints?

Please don't provide full solution. Only hints for doing faster calculations. Reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think that there is an efficient method in general determining the exact number.